# How to convert mySQL code to Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

how can I change mySQL code to work in Oracle SQL 11g

```
SELECT a.boxid, 
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( b.quantity, \' x \', c.name ) SEPARATOR \', \' ) Items
FROM box a
INNER JOIN item_line b ON a.boxid = b.boxid
INNER JOIN items c ON b.itemid = c.itemid
```

The output of this query looks like this:

```
boxid     items
1         2 x ball,4 x bat
2         ball
3         3 x cap,2 x ball,bat
4         2 x ball
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LISTAGG()`

```
SELECT  boxid,
        LISTAGG(quantity || ' x ' || name, ',') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY boxid) AS items
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY boxid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af4d9/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*if you want `1 x` to suppress*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af4d9/6)
- [Oracle LISTAGG()](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Oracle's SQL Developer Migration (which is a free product). The docs say it will help migrate Microsoft Access, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL and Sybase to Oracle:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration//workbench/index%5Fsqldev%5Fomwb.html

Comment: This link appears to be broken